# Accessing local assembly ValueConverters

Tags: wpf, local, xml-namespaces

I am having some problems trying to add a ValueConverter in my xaml usercontrol:

at start I had problems just to add the reference to the local namespace, after some compiling/cleaning/recompiling it seems to finally see itself. Still, it says that my ValueConverter class cannot be found, to check that the assembly is referenced blah blah blah..

This is my XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MySolution.GUI.StatusPanel"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="using:MySolution.GUI"
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MySolution.Styles;component/Styles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MySolution.Styles;component/Icons.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <Style ...>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Column2, Converter={local:RowValueConverter}}" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
...
</UserControl>
```

And this is the converter:

```
namespace MySolution.GUI
{
    public class RowValueConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what I don't understand is why it keeps on saying that 
the tag 'RowValueConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:MySolution.GUI'

How can I fix this?

Thanks

**Edit: current status of XAML file**

```
...
xmlns:local="using:MySolution.GUI"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:RowValueConverter x:Key="rowValueConverter" />
    <ResourceDictionary>
    ...
    ...
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Column2, Converter={StaticResource rowValueConverter}}" />
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT updated answer based on comment**

Add following

```
 < local:RowValueConverter x:key="rowValueConverter" />
```

after

```
 < UserControl.Resources>
```

Change following

```
Converter={local:RowValueConverter}
```

To

```
Converter={StaticResource rowValueConverter}
```

You have not defined the resource anywhere, and trying to use class name instead of resource in existing code

---

**Old answer**

Change

```
xmlns:local="MySolution.GUI"
```

to

```
xmlns:local="using:MySolution.GUI"
```

or

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MySolution.GUI"
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad.. still, if I use "using:" I still get the same error, the tag doesn't exist; if I use "clr-namespace:" instead it says that the CLR namespace is not defined.

Comment: Still nothing, tag 'RowValueConverter' does not exist and Type 'local:RowValueConverter' not found...

Comment: is there any possibility that by chance same namespace is defined in multiple assembilies

Comment: I did a full scan of the solution just to be sure.. no, it's the only assembly.

Comment: hit and trial, can u remove the reference from the xaml, then compile, then put the reference back. Or you can post the minimalistic code (including project, solution) somewhere.

Comment: I made some tests, new projects, and it seems the problem stems from the fact that the namespace uses a Pascal naming type in the final part? is that even possible? I mean "COMPANY.SOFTWARE.PROJECT.Module" works correctly, but "COMPANY.SOFTWARE.PROJECT.ModuleName" won't.. that's strange

Comment: strange to me also. I have never tried, and hence not faced this issue